# Django Time Date Models

Tags: python, django

What is the best field type/field option for a model that should only contain the date and month.

```
class Reminder(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
    reminder_one = models.???
    reminder_two = models.???
```

As I want to input a date that will act as a reminder each year I want to ensure no year is entered.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just store it as a date(with a year) but only check against its Month Day attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two standard Django date fields-

`DateField`
`DateTimeField`

I suggest you use datefield and use the default querysets to sort by month and day:

[QuerySets - Month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month)

Otherwise, you would need to store the month and day as a string, and that gets messy and is just unnecessary.